# Passing parameters to a method incompatible type

Tags: java, sorting, parameters, parameter-passing

Can someone please tell me what am i not seeing.
Exercise from a book.
Create a class called SortingTest. In it, create a method that accepts an array of int values as a parameter and prints out to the terminal the elements sorted.(smallest elements first)

When trying to compile, I'm getting an error:incompatible types.
AbcArray cannot be converted to int[]
From my understanding,I'm passing an int[] value to a method that expects an int[] value. (I apologize if my error is so obvious, i'm still learning)

```
public class AbcArray {

   private int[] myArray;

   public AbcArray(){
     myArray = new int[]{55,58,57,54,56};
   }

   public int[] theValues(){
     return myArray;
   }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortingTest{

  public SortingTest() {}

  public void sortArray(int[] outsideArray){
    Arrays.sort(outsideArray);
    System.out.println(outsideArray);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not calling sortArray in your code. Missing `main`?

Comment: @Adrian ,Im using BlueJ IDE

Comment: @RyanG that wasn't the question. You say "I'm passing an int[] value to a method that expects an int[] value" - where do you do that? You didn't post your ``main`` method.

Comment: @f1sh a BlueJ project has no Main method. He does that manually.

Comment: @Tom BlueJ is simply an IDE, of course he needs a main method to run the whole thing. What does he do manually? And where?

Comment: Let me guess you're creating an instance of AbcArray and then you're trying to pass that reference to that method. Why do you think that your instance is suddenly an int[], rather the AbcArray reference?

Comment: @Tom im sorry, i can't understand what you have just said. from what i know, im passing myArray(which is of type int[])  to the sortArray which expects int[].

Comment: @f1sh That is wrong. You don't need a main method (BlueJ will still create one, but this is unrelated). In BlueJ you can create instances bei clicking on one of your classes and BlueJ will collect and show them to the user. He then can interact with them, using the UI.

Comment: Ryan, no, AbcArray has an int array, it isn't one. You need to pass the result of abcarray.theValues() to your method. (with abcarray I mean your instance of that class).

Comment: @RyanG Your input for the `#sortArray` method should look like this: http://i.imgur.com/X2c6Q9s.png.

Comment: @Tom thank you very much! I was afraid im not going to get the right answer because not everyone knows BlueJ

Comment: @RyanG You're welcome :). Btw, you should use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outsideArray));` to print the array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First issue with your code is wrong constructor in `AbcArray` code. You need to replace

```
public ArraysData(){
    myArray = new int[]{55,58,57,54,56};
}
```

with

```
public AbcArray(){
    myArray = new int[]{55,58,57,54,56};
}
```

Next step is missing code you didn't post. Let's assume it looks as follows:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        AbcArray a = new AbcArray();
        SortingTest st = new SortingTest();

        st.sortArray(a);
    }
}
```

Attempt to build this code results in `actual argument AbcArray cannot be converted to int[] by method invocation conversion`. This happens because you are passing the whole class `AbcArray` to method `sortArray` to fix that you need to pass values from `AbcArray` which are available by using method `theValues()`. So your code will looks like this:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        AbcArray a = new AbcArray();
        SortingTest st = new SortingTest();

        st.sortArray(a.theValues());
    }
}
```

Also you can't print array into standard output. Take a look at `Arrays.toString()` method before printing anything.

Comment: @f1sh Because this answer also asserts, that OP needs a `main` method, which is _wrong_. If he removes that, I would remove my vote, because the other stuff is correct.